# Why when i use "#pragma omp parallel for" program work incorrect

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I try to write parallel program but when i put "#pragma omp parallel for" in output i get incorrect.
Hyperbolic partial differential equation.
Please help me.

```
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(9)
        for(i = 1; i < XMAX - 1; i++){
            for(j = 1; j < TMAX - 1; j++){
            U[i][j + 1] = 2 * U[i][j] - U[i][j - 1] + sigma * (U[i + 1][j] - 2*U[i][j] + U[i - 1][j]) + (TAU*TAU * f(x[i],t[i]));
            }
        }
```

what i need to get
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgdAc.png)

and what i get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHAYV.png)

Comment: You have a very basic race condition. Please try to learn about basic parallel processing.

Comment: Also don't put textual results into images. Put them into code blocks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OPENMP - Parallelize Schwarz algorithm with preconditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47450267/openmp-parallelize-schwarz-algorithm-with-preconditions)

Comment: Declare your loop variables in the loop header. That prevents the race condition on the shared `j` variable. Do not put the number of threads in the code: use an `OMP_NUM_THREADS` environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

Each `j+1` depends on `j` and `j-1` so the `j` loop has to be sequential: use that as outer loop, and not parallel.

However, `[i][j+1]` does not depend on any other `[i+whatever][j+1]` so the `i` iterations can be done in parallel: have the `i` loop as inner, and make it parallel.

(And please put the loop variables in the header: `for (int i=whatever)`. Declaring everything up front is bad style, and with OpenMP it easily leads to errors.)

Answer (score -3):

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(3)
for(j = 1; j < TMAX - 1; j++){
    for(i = 1; i < XMAX - 1; i++){
        U[i][j + 1] = 2 * U[i][j] - U[i][j - 1] + sigma * (U[i + 1][j] - 2*U[i][j] + U[i - 1][j]) + (TAU*TAU * f(x[i],t[i]));
    }
}
```

You need just change "i" and "j" rows.

Comment: I doubt that this is correct. Each `[j+1]` index depends on `[j]` so you can not execute the `j` iterations in arbitrary order.